# Use groovy-wslite make a post request from CURL request

Tags: rest, curl, groovy

Hi i have the following CURL request that i'd like to include in a groovy script using the groovy-wslite library put struggling to get the request working.

```
curl -s -X POST -k -u user:password https://artifactory_url/api/search/aql -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d 'items.find({"type":"file","repo":{"$eq": "my-repo-name"},"path":{"$match":"com/mycompany/product1/subcat/mob/*"},"name":{"$match":"*apk"}}).sort({"$desc":["path"]}).limit(1)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [http-builder-ng](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5) and your code could look like

```
compile 'io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-CLIENT:1.0.4'
```

```
HttpBuilder.configure {
    request.uri = 'https://artifactory_url/api/search/aql'
    request.auth.basic 'un', 'pw'
    request.contentType = 'text/plain'
}.post {
    request.body = 'items.find({"type":"file","repo":{"$eq": "my-repo-name"},"path":{"$match":"com/mycompany/product1/subcat/mob/*"},"name":{"$match":"*apk"}}).sort({"$desc":["path"]}).limit(1)'

    response.success { FromServer fs, Object body ->
        println body
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant a nice library and thank you for your example too! :-)